# Position a set of points such that they are all optimally a certain distance from the origin

Tags: linear-transformations, analytic-geometry, numerical-linear-algebra

This is a very specific question and since I am no mathematician by trade I did not really figure out how to ask it in mathematical jargon, I apologize in advance for the inconvenience.

This is a problem I stumbled upon while doing regular linear algebra for an application for computational chemistry. It showed up in a subroutine to assemble the geometry of a large, complicated molecule which I had to do one piece at a time. I jotted down a few trials on how to solve this, but it got me stumped real fast and I can't find a way out.

Stripped from its chemical details, the problem is as such.

Suppose there is a set of points $\mathcal{S}$ in 3D Euclidian space $\mathbb{R}^3$ which is a subset of a larger set $\mathcal{A}$. Each of these points have a color. They can all be the same color or each be a different color or any combination of colors. Each color $c$ is associated with a certain distance $d_c$. This value $d_c$ is the *optimal distance* from the origin for the points of color $c$.

The solution to the problem would be to find the rotations and translations that transform the **entire** set of points $\mathcal{A}$ such that the norm of the position vector $|\vec{p}_i|$ of each point in $\mathcal{S}$ is as close as possible to each of their optimal distances.

**So the question is:** Is it possible to find the rotation matrices and translation vectors that accomplish that? Is there a procedure to do it?

P.S: It is important that the transformations be applied to all the points in $\mathcal{A}$ **simultaneously**.

Comment: Note that you don't need rotations: once you figure out the correct translation, rotating the system around the origin won't change the distances.

Comment: The points initially are haphazardly oriented in space. Since each is a different color, putting them all around the origin might not be the optimal solution. Also, if the distances are too short, that is also undesirable. The solution will have the distances as close to the optimal as possible. Neither above nor below.

Comment: Interesting problem, but I don't think it's stated clearly enough. In general, you clearly can't position the structure so that each point is as close as possible to its optimal distance. For each particle, you could easily position it to its optimal distance, but you can't do that for all of them simultaneously. So do you want to minimize the sum of the squared differences between the actual and optimal distances? Note also that per TomKern rotations don't help: any rotation can be expressed as a translation plus a rotation about the origin, and rotations about the origin don't do anything.

Comment: I have provided further clarification. Also, there were aspects of the question that I had no idea were important, and have been clarified in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your description it looks like all the points are fixed relative to each other.  In that case, the only freedom is locating the origin.   Let $d_k$ be the optimum distance for point $k$ while $s_k(x)$ is the distance when the origin is at a point $x$.  Your problem is minimizing $\sum\limits_k (d_k-s_k(x))^2$ as a function of $x$.

Alternatively you might want to minimize $\sum\limits_k |d_k-s_k(x)|$.

Specifically, let $(y_{1k},y_{2k},y_{3k})$ be the location of point $k$ and $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ the origin.  So $s_k(x)=\sqrt{\sum\limits_{j=1}^3(y_{jk}-x_j)^2}$